# Reset bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

So, I am using bootstrap's modal.

I want to make a wizard style modal and came up with the following solution:

div snippets:

```
<div class="modal-instance hide fade" id="step1">
 <div id="stepa">
  ...
 </div>
</div>


<div id="stepb" style="display: none;">
 ...
</div>
```

Upon pressing a button in step-a step-b is loaded.

javascript snippet:

```
$("#stepa").replaceWith($('#stepb'));
document.getElementById('stepb').style.display = 'block';
```

This works ok.

But when I dismiss the modal. The div stepa has still been replaced by stepb. My solution was to build a replacement back to stepa when the modal is hidden:

```
$("#myModal").on("hidden", function() { 
//replace the child
});
```

I tried:

```
$('#step1').children().remove();
$('#step1').append($('#stepa'));
```

and

```
$("#step1").children("div:first").replaceWith($('#stepa'));
```

But I am having a hardtime selecting step-a as a replacement div, probably due to it not being a separate div. My question is, is this the right approach for a wizard styled modal or should I take another approach?

Comment: $('#step1').children().remove(); you need to add '.remove'

Comment: @IvoJonkers It is removing the children already, just not adding step-a back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much simpler just to hide the previous and next steps, instead of copying them.

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch modal</button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" data-step="1">
 <div class="step step1">
  <h1>Step 1</h1>
  <button class="btn next">Next</button>
 </div>
 <div class="step step2">
  <h1>Step 2</h1>
  <button class="btn previous">Previous</button>
  <button class="btn next">Next</button>
 </div>
 <div class="step step3">
  <h1>Step 3</h1>
  <button class="btn previous">Previous</button>
  <button class="btn done" data-dismiss="modal">Done</button>
 </div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
  #myModal > .step { display: none; }​
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
  showStep(parseInt($('#myModal').data('step')) || 1);

  $('#myModal .next').on('click', function () {
   showStep(parseInt($('#myModal').data('step')) + 1);
  });

  $('#myModal .previous').on('click', function () {
   showStep(parseInt($('#myModal').data('step')) - 1);
  });

  $('#myModal').on('hidden', function() {
   showStep(1);
  });

  function showStep(step) {
   $('#myModal').data('step', step);
   $('#myModal > .step').hide();
   $('#myModal > .step' + step).show();
  }
 });​
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7kg7z/5/

Comment: Thank you very much, seems a more logic approach. I can work with that.

Comment: Weird, somehow I can't get step3 to show. Only when I manually edit the step3 style to display: block; It will show. I have simply extended the css and div with an step 3 but am I missing something else?

Comment: Could not edit my own comment: Interesting, I eddited your jsfiddle and it worked beautifully.. weird stuff.

Comment: Thinking about it. It might be easier to show and hide using JS, since adding steps in CSS is a (small) pain. http://jsfiddle.net/7kg7z/4/

Comment: Thank you, I have successfully implemented your code into my project.